# Dynamically JDBC Property loading using postProcessBeanFactory

Tags: spring-jdbc

I am doing dynamically `jdbc` properties loading using `postProcessBeanFactory`.

But I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from class path resource [BeansJdbc.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'bean' must have no character [children], because the types content type is element-only.
```

This is my `OurLogic.java`:

```
package com.madhubanti.spring.jdbc;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

/**
 * @author Madhubanti
 *
 */
public class OurLogic {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeansJdbc.xml");
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/jdbcBund.properties"));
        ppc.postProcessBeanFactory(context.getBeanFactory());

        SpringJdbcCreateTable obj = (SpringJdbcCreateTable)context.getBean("id3");
        obj.createTable();
    }

}

BeansJdbc.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="id1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
               
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.className}" />
               
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
               
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
               
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="id2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="id1" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="id3" class="com.madhubanti.spring.jdbc.SpringJdbcCreateTable">
        <property name="jt">
            <ref bean="id2" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>

jdbcbund.properties:
jdbc.className = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
jdbc.user = system
jdbc.pass = password

SpringJdbcCreateTable.java:

/**
 * 
 */
package com.madhubanti.spring.jdbc;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

/**
 * @author Madhubanti
 *
 */
public class SpringJdbcCreateTable {

    JdbcTemplate jt ;

    public void setJt(JdbcTemplate jt){
        this.jt = jt;
    }

    public void createTable(){
        jt.execute("create table person (name varchar2(100) primary key, height number (3,2))");
        // execute returns void
        System.out.println("The table person has got created");
    }


}
```

May you please say where is the issue?

Comment: Read the error message carefully, it explains the problem (starting from `Line 11 in XML document from class path resource [BeansJdbc.xml] is invalid`)

Comment: Hi, I have got the issue...There were some unwanted characters pasted which were hidden when I copied it from a tutorial and pasted in my BeanJdbc.xml. Now I have typed manually ${jdbc.url},..etc(The db properties) and it is working fine. In between I changed ApplicationContext thing to BeanFactory, but was getting the same issue. Then manually typed the db properties in the xml as read in another thread of stack overflow that this issue can be caused due to unwanted hidden characters. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your help.